# Heroku/Django: Project isn't migrating, throws error about missing tables when you run manage.py migrate

Tags: django, heroku

I've got some issues with a project I made. Everything tests good locally but after I got it onto Heroku, it doesn't work. It's complaining about missing tables which, I thought, would be created when I migrated it but that isn't working. The database is currently empty. I'm using dj_database_url for the setup on Heroku.

Error:

```
    Running bash on ⬢ fcf-demo... up, run.6802 (Free)
~ $ python FatCatFish/manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "temperatures_sourcemap" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "temperatures_sourcemap" W...
                                          ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FatCatFish/manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "FatCatFish/manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/FatCatFish/FatCatFish/urls.py", line 25, in <module>
    path('', include('temperatures.urls')),
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/FatCatFish/temperatures/urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .api import TempViewSet, SourceMapViewSet, ChartsViewSet, RemoteViewSet
  File "/app/FatCatFish/temperatures/api.py", line 8, in <module>
    class TempViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  File "/app/FatCatFish/temperatures/api.py", line 9, in TempViewSet
    count = SourceMap.objects.all().filter(active=True).count()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 397, in count
    return self.query.get_count(using=self.db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 517, in get_count
    number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 502, in get_aggregation
    result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1144, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "temperatures_sourcemap" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "temperatures_sourcemap" W...
```

Comment: The line `count = SourceMap.objects.all().filter(active=True).count()` is running when the modules are imported, before `makemigrations` can create the table. The proper fix would be to move that code into a method so that it doesn’t run when the module is imported. As a hack, you could probably comment it out while you run makemigrations.